# Qual è il significato di "spiazzo battuto"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> I carbonai, sullo **spiazzo battuto di terra cenerina**, erano i più numerosi. Urlavano «Hura! Hota!» perché erano gente bergamasca e non la si capiva nel parlare.

La mia domanda è sul senso dell'espressione "spiazzo battuto di terra cenerina" che appare in questo passaggio. Ha un significato simile a quello di ["terra battuta"](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/terra-battuta), cioè, si tratterebbe di uno spiazzo che è stato spianato in qualche modo?

Comment: Uno spiazzo di terra battuta dal colore di cenere perché era usato dai carbonai. “Hura e hota” vuol dire “sopra e sotto” (i bergamaschi fanno diventare la esse sorda un'aspirazione).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il significato è quello indicato da te, cioè uno [spiazzo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spiazzo/) ovvero

> spazio libero, per lo più pianeggiante, di una certa ampiezza

di terra battuta color cenere.

La [terra battuta](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_battuta) è una pavimentazione realizzata in terra che viene spianata utilizzando macchinari ed utilizzata, ad esempio, nei campi da tennis.
In alcuni casi possono anche essere utilizzati altri materiali finemente triturati e poi spianati con un rullo compressore.

La terra battuta a cui fa riferimento l'autore probabilmente è un'area dove la terra è diventata dura a causa del calpestio di uomini, mezzi e animali.

Comment: Potresti indicare la fonte della citazione?

Comment: @Charo Riferimenti aggiunti.